Azure Service Bus Queue Groups
I would like to get the same functionality as I believe queue groups in Nats provides, but I have to use Azure (Service Bus?) My first question is: is this possible? If so, any pointers greatly received.
By way of an example, I essentially want my app, that has four load balanced servers, to publish to a "topic" (each server publishes its own messages, but not duplicate messages) and then two separate apps (e.g. event processing / audit logging) to retrieve those messages, but only on one of the servers in each of the subscribing queue groups if that makes sense?
Many thanks for any information provided.


ASB supports competing consumers on queues and subscriptions. A subscription is a "queue group" if I understand the terminology correctly.

Did you try anything?

I am using queues on ASB elsewhere, but I can't find any documentation specifically on this so my guess is they are either describing it differently or they don't support it...

Yes, correct, so a topic must have a subscription for each entity you wish to receive the messages. Each subscription is essentially a queue group I believe. You can not specify the queue group on the client and must predefine the subscriptions. You can create subscriptions programmatically, but that makes the task much harder.

Thanks for the inputs @Sean Feldman and I do that you can use Azure Service Bus Topics where we can create multiple subscriptions, in that each subscription can behave as the queue.

and now you can send messages to different subscriptions.

So, for each subscription queue we can send messages separately.

Hi, yes, thanks for this. I was just experimenting with it and came to this same conclusion. Rather annoyingly, it's stupid hard to create subscriptions dynamically though.

Yes, that true..

Yes, will do. By way of additional information, it will be necessary for me to set up a service principal with a client secret that I can use for creating the subscriptions. Going to give that a try next week. In the meantime, I'm "temporarily" using NATS on Synadia Cloud until we can get that working...
